# Qual a diferença entre o sinal + e - em Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Queria saber qual a diferença na hora de cria um método utilizando o "+" e "-"?

E também quando devo usar e porque usar, geralmente só uso o "-", mas não sei como utilizar o método com "+".

Obrigado.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É assim, os métodos com prefixo `-` são métodos de instância, ou seja, você só pode chamar esses métodos através de uma instância da classe:

```
NSString *instanciaString = [[NSString alloc] init];
[instanciaString length];
```

E os métodos com o prefixo `+` são métodos de classe. Esses métodos não precisam de uma instância para serem chamados, você pode chamar direto da classe, por exemplo:

```
[NSString stringWithString:@"Hello World"];
```